# Rails filtering partial results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering a todo list for a user like so

```
<%= render @user.todos %>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to show only the ones that have been marked as completed.

Is this something that I should be doing in a controller or model, or is it ok to filter something like that in a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like a named scope on the todo model which returns completed todos so you can then do

```
<%= render @user.todos.completed %>
```

Comment: This is also the way I would do it.  It is the most explicit for your views and will place the necessary logic for filtering objects based on state within the Model itself.

Answer (score 1):

The logic should always go into your Model.

You should create a :scope (rails 3) or :default_scope (Rails 2) in your model and call it in the View directly. Something like completed_todos and then you can call @user.completed_todos. You simply set completed = true in the scope.

Hope this helps.